# Axios await axios.get() not honored in a useEffect(, []) sequence with multiple operations

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a `useEffect(.., [])` initialization sequence which involves 2 operations, each an `await`-blocked sync Axios call.

I verified that the 1st Axios call `await` call is **not** honored and the flow jumps to the 2nd `useEffect` operation, `getFlag()`, right after the await axios.get() line. Does anyone know why?

```
useEffect(() => {    

    getAgreements(); // Step 1

    getFlag(); // Step 2

}, []); 



const getAgreements = async () => {

    const url = '/getAgreements';

    try {

        const response = await axios.get(url); // This 'await' is not honored, jumps to getFlag()

        setAgreementsList(response.data);

    }

    catch (error) { 

        setErrorObj({message: error.message, location: 'Agreements.js: getAgreements'});

    }

    finally {

        setIsLoading(false);

    }

}   

const getFlag = async () => {

    const url = '/getNewAgreementIndicator';

    try {

        const response = await axios.get(url);

        setNewAgreementFlag(response.data);

    }

    catch (error) { 

        setErrorObj({message: error.message, location: 'Agreements.js: getNewAgreementIndicator'});

    }

    finally {

        setIsLoading(false);

    }

}
```

When I rewrite the code below with `.then()` I see that in the 2nd fetch, the `await` is not honored, and it goes to `console.log()` before the result of the 2nd fetch is returned. Can anyone clarify?

```
useEffect(() => {    
    getAgreements()
    .then(() => {
        getFlag()
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('test');
    })

}, []);
```

Comment: Your `useEffect` callback doesn't handle the promises from `getAgreements` _or_ `getFlag`. Try e.g. `getAgreements().then(() => getFlag())` if you need them to be strictly in series.

Comment: I rewrote the code with `.then()` like you said, but now the 2nd `await` is not honored: I updated my OP. Now in the 2nd fetch the code jumps after the axios.get().

Comment: Note I returned the promise from `getFlag` into the promise chain, your code explicitly does not.

Comment: Where did you "return the promise from `getFlag` into the promise chain?"

Comment: `.then(() => getFlag())` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#basic_syntax

Comment: Is it possible to be more explicit with `return ...` so it's clearer?

Comment: Yes - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#basic_syntax again

Answer (score 1):

Wouldnt it be better to just have 2 use effects rather than all of them in the one that happens on mount? Have another useEffect which gets triggered when the agreementsList gets update

```js
useEffect(() => {    
    getAgreements(); // Step 1
}, []); 

useEffect(() => {    
  if(agreementsList){
    getFlag(); // Step 2
  }
}, [agreementsList]);
```

Comment: The problem is that the Axios `await axios.get()` is not blocked until the next line, and it jumps to another `useEffect`. That is true regardless of whether you have one or several useEffects.

Comment: @geneb. no, the `await` in `getAgreements` _does_ "block" prior to `setAgreementsList` being reached - it yields control back to the caller, which in your original formulation _isn't_ awaiting it so proceeds to immediately call `getFlag`.

Comment: jonrsharpe, for the benefit of others reading this, it would be useful to provide a clear answer with code, and without the cryptic hidden returns as well, by the way. BTW: While I got it to work like you said in a **single** useEffect multi-op sequence, it still doesn't work with **multiple useEffects** !

Comment: @geneb. re _"cryptic hidden returns"_ I'd strongly recommend you familiarise yourself with basic ES6 syntax, you're going to have a hard time in React without this as most docs/examples/tutorials etc. assume it.